# Find & Replace Merged Cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, find-and-replace

I've searched for solutions but in my version of Excel and others I've tried (Excel 2016 and Excel 2008), I don't see any option to Find Format in order to find Merged Cells like all the tutorials I've found say to use. So I'm stuck with a list of 9000 records and I can't sort or find the merged cells.

This is a screenshot of my Find/Replace dialog

[image]

Am I missing something? I've done everything I can do in terms of trying to find where to find the Find Merged Cells option.

Comment: [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-merged-cells-D02B2A5A-A08D-4641-8D4D-B3F233DACA2C) seems pretty clear and straightforward to me. Just tested it and it works fine in 2016

Comment: Any way you could elaborate? I added a screenshot of where the "find format" option is supposed to be, based on the tutorials I've found. But it's not there. Where did you find the option?

Answer (score 0):

I used 2019 (Build 1912) and it would not find a merged cell set, either with Find or Find & Replace.

I even used `Choose Format From Cell` in Find so that the formatting I sought was obviously identical to the cells I sought.

Interestingly, in F&R, the merged cell option was not available and choosing the formatting from a cell failed altogether. My wager is that that is because F&R will find A cell and act upon A cell, but the merge format involves at least 2 cells so it might not (in the programmers' minds) know what to do in all cases, so it does nothing, not even offered.

As to why it works for cybernetic.nomad and all the tutorials you found... no clue. Finding tons of tutorials is not, in itself, more than one fact given how lots of folks will push the same wrong information. Not saying they plagerize wrong test answers, but when tutorials follow the same path, right down to emphasizing the same odd things, well, all but one is plagerizing someone. The odd thing is they don't always check. I had issues with everyone's explanation about getting Unicode character to come up properly and finally complained to one author. He actually dug in and found the problem. Hopefully he then changed his own tutorial somewhat.

But cybernetic.nomad says it works. That, with the last bit above, says to me that it really does in Find, though clearly not in F&R since it doesn't even offer to include merged cells, and that there is just some little thing that folks overlook. Perhaps it is beyond basic to them, being their default for 30 years, that kind of thing, and maybe a bunch are plagerismn (as in slightly rewritten, certainly never checked on their own systems before publishing). Just some little thing, some quirky way of understanding a bit of phraseology that makes it all make sense if you catch on.

But you DO have to use Find, not F&R, at least in 2019.

Answer (score 0):

An update... slightly newer version of Excel nine months later, but cannot say if I missed this before or if it has been adjusted.

However, opening `Find and Replace` and choosing `Options` in the lower right corner, then `Format` above it by the `Find what:` line... I now find very much every format available via `Ctrl-1` to be available here and sure enough, checking `Merge cells` on the `Alignment` tab is possible.

And finds the merged cells. I didn't test it beyond this, but I'm sure I could replace that formatting with whatever 'cause the same options are available by the `Replace with` line.

I have to think I was doing something wrong before, but in any case, the current version of desktop Excel (O365) has what the poster needs.